# (JQuery Mobile/ JavaScript) Mobile phone send sms at backend not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twilio-click-to-call

Thank you for taking the time to read this post. 
Basically, I am trying to code a mobile app which one of its features requires making a mobile phone to send a message (local/overseas message) at the backend (without letting the "user" know). It's a company mobile phone (ios/android) and the number belongs to the company.   Besides, the condition is offline.

I tried to use href tag to send the message but it doesn't work for me. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to send the message from the user's device? That is, it will be sent from their number, but without their knowledge?

Comment: yes, i am trying to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can only use the device's APIs to send SMS messages from a user's number on Android. iOS does not let you do this in the background or hidden from the user.

For Android, I encourage you to follow this tutorial on [sending SMS messages from Android](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm).

The key point is that, if you have the `SEND_SMS` permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Then you can send an SMS message with these lines of code:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```

If you are using JavaScript, presumably via cordova or similar, then you will likely need a plugin to achieve this. The [cordova-sms](https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin) plugin seems like it might work for you on Android.